# "Programming In Haskell" error in sat function

Tags: haskell

I'm in chapter 8 of Graham Hutton's Programming in Haskell and I'm copying the code and testing it in GHC.

See the slides here: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~sueo/cis352/chapter8.pdf in particular slide 15

The relevant code I've copied so far is:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]
pih_return :: a -> Parser a
pih_return v = \inp -> [(v, inp)]
failure :: Parser a
failure = \inp -> []
item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of
                    [] -> []
        (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]
parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse p inp = p inp
sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do x <- item
           if p x then pih_return x else failure
```

I have changed the name of the `return` function from the book to `pih_return` so that it doesn't clash with the Prelude `return` function.

The errors are in the last function `sat`. I have copied this directly from the book.

As you can probably see `p` is a function from `Char` to `Bool` (e.g. `isDigit`) and `x` is of type `[(Char, String)]`, so that's the first error.

Then `pih_return` takes a value `v` and returns `[(v, inp)]` where `inp` is a `String`. This causes an error in `sat` because the `v` being passed is `x` which is not a `Char`.

I have come up with this solution, by explicitly including `inp` into `sat`

```
sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p inp = do x <- item inp
               if p (fst x) then pih_return (fst x) inp else failure inp
```

Is this the best way to solve the issue?

Comment: Slide 11 in that deck points to the full library version, which @Rüdiger Hanke, below, has given the link to. Indeed, the slide deck doesn't make it clear that all the code before slide 11 is just a first version, and all the code after slide 11 is meant to be used with the Monadic version in the library file.

Comment: Ah. Thanks, MntViewMark. That explains things. It's not properly mentioned in the book either, only in the remarks at the end of the chapter where he says, "For technical reasons concerning the monadic nature of parsers, a number of the basic definitions in [the] library are slightly different to those given here".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `sat` can't work, `Parser` must be a monad in order to use the `do` notation. In order to make it a monad instance, `newtype` would have to be used.

I don't own the book, but I suppose the author wanted to start with a simple parser type and later extend it to a full monad and I suspect that you have mixed up definitions of the non-monadic versions with one of the `Parser` monad (`sat`) and missed the monad instance declaration along the way.

There's code from the chapter available [on the author's web site](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/Parsing.lhs) where a monad instance has been defined for `Parser`.

If you must write a `sat` function for the simple `Parser` type I'd rather do it in lambda-style (as `item`) and avoid monads entirely (you noticed that the original `sat`'s `do`block was a `Parser`monad and yours is a `List` monad?). And I *think* you have a bug in your `sat` version: rather than `pih_return (fst x) inp`, I think it should be `pih_return (fst x) (snd x)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Looking at the code from the website, it is noticeably different from the book. The book doesn't mention monads at this point.

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing me to the website. Google hasn't found it and it has the errata in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `do` notation without a monad, and you can't make a monad instance unless you use `data` or `newtype`, and you can't use `data` or `newtype` unless you introduce an annoying value constructor.  Undoubtedly the value constructor has been omitted just because it *is* annoying.

In the example below you can see that I've used `newtype` and have introduced the annoying value constructor `Parser`.  This is what makes the `instance` declaration work, and at this point you can use not only `do`-notation but also the standard monadic `return` and `fail`.

This code compiles without errors or warnings:

```
module P
where

newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a, String)])
instance Monad Parser where
  return a = Parser $ \inp -> [(a, inp)]
  fail _   = Parser $ \_   -> []
  Parser f >>= k = Parser $ \inp -> 
     [(b, inp'') | (a, inp') <- f inp, let Parser g = k a, (b, inp'') <- g inp']

item :: Parser Char
item = Parser $ \inp -> case inp of
                          [] -> []
                          (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]
parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse (Parser p) inp = p inp
sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do x <- item
           if p x then return x else fail "predicate not satisfied"
```

Answer (score 1):

The slides are missing the implementation of the `Monad` typeclass for the type `Parser`.

With that declaration, the `do` notation is correct; `x <- item` actually does the correct unwrapping from `[(Char, String)]` to `(Char, String)`.

I can't seem to get this definition without compiling it to see the error but it's a start:

```
instance Monad (Parser a) where
  return x = pih_return x
  -- (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
  p >>= f = \inp -> case p inf of
                      [] -> []
                      (x:xs) -> (f x) xs -- this line is probably wrong
  fail message = [] -- message is ignored
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan. The book mentions p >>= f using a slightly different syntax, but I imagine that is due to monads not being explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading the very same book and arrived at the same problem when trying to do the excercises. I reverted from using the 'do ...' notation to the >>=. For anyone interested I enclosed my code up to using the nat function. I prepended all my functions with a and changed >>= to >>>= in order to avoid name collisions with prelude.

```
type AParser a = String -> [(a, String)]
areturn :: a -> AParser a
areturn v = \inp -> [(v, inp)]
afailure :: AParser a
afailure = \inp -> []
aitem :: AParser Char
aitem = \inp -> case inp of
                  [] -> []
                  (x:xs) -> [(x, xs)]
aparse :: AParser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
aparse p inp = p inp
(>>>=) :: AParser a -> (a -> AParser b) -> AParser b
p >>>= f = \inp -> case aparse p inp of
                    [] -> []
                    [(v, out)] -> aparse (f v) out
(+++) :: AParser a -> AParser a -> AParser a
p +++ q = \inp -> case aparse p inp of
                    [] -> aparse q inp
                    [(v, out)] -> [(v, out)]
asat :: (Char -> Bool) -> AParser Char
asat p = aitem >>>= (\x -> if p x then areturn x else afailure)
adigit :: AParser Char
adigit = asat isDigit
amany :: AParser a -> AParser [a]
amany p = amany1 p +++ areturn []
amany1 :: AParser a -> AParser [a]
amany1 p = p >>>= (\v -> (amany p) >>>= (\vs -> areturn (v:vs)))
anat :: AParser Int
anat = amany1 adigit >>>= (\xs -> areturn (read xs))
```